# How to use reverse ssh tunneling with multiple jump servers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

How would I use SSH Tunneling for an architecture in the example below?

Scenario:  I am physically logged into Windows PC Local and wish to remote desktop into the Windows PC Remote using port 3389. There is a firewall between Windows PC Local and the Network A Linux Server that only allows me to SSH from PC local to the Linux Server on Network A.  Is it possible to establish a reverse tunnel on the Network A Linux Server through to the Windows PC Remote? I am thinking that 3 or more tunnels would have to be established and linked together to accomplish this, but I don't know how to do it or know if it is possible.

```
Windows PC Local    Linux Server   .-,(  ),-.         can ssh                     Linux Server    Windows PC Remote
     __| _             __| _    .-(          )-.----------------->    .-,(  ),-.       __| _         __  _|        
    [__]|=|-----------[__]|=|---(  Network A   )                   .-(          )-.   [__]|=|-------[__]|=|        
    /::/|_|           /::/|_|   '-(         ).-'                   (    Network B  )--/::/|_|       /::/|_|        
                                   '-.( ).-'   <-----------------   '-(        ).-'                                
                                                      can't ssh        '-.( ).-'
```

Comment: how many Linux servers are involved here?

Comment: There are two.   One on Network A and one on Network B. PC's are behind each. As per diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually accomplish this with a single SSH tunnel between the two Linux servers, more specifically from the one on Network A to the one on Network B (the direction in which it can SSH.)

Assuming you want to remote desktop into the Remote Windows machine (the one on the side of Network B), then you need a *direct* SSH tunnel.

(A reverse SSH tunnel would be if you wanted to expose a service from a machine in network A to machines in network B through this SSH connection initiated on the Linux server in network A.)

To understand how to set this up, let's assign some IP addresses and names to the machines and interfaces involved. Otherwise, it's hard to understand which exact addresses and names go where.

Let's use these addresses for the local network:

```
Windows PC Local               Linux Server           .-,(  ),-.   
 __| _                            __| _            .-(          )-.
[__]|=|--------------------------[__]|=|-----------(  Network A   )
/::/|_|                          /::/|_|           '-(         ).-'
    192.168.10.7      192.168.10.4    301.2.3.4       '-.( ).-'    
    workstation7        linrouter4    a.example.com
```

Then these addresses for the remote network:

```
                         Linux Server               Windows PC Remote
   .-,(  ),-.                 __| _                            __  _|
.-(          )-.             [__]|=|--------------------------[__]|=|
(    Network B  )------------/::/|_|                          /::/|_|
 '-(        ).-'     321.9.8.7    172.24.10.99     172.24.10.76      
    '-.( ).-'    b.example.net    gateway1.lan     remote76.lan
```

Visualizing only the interconnect between the two Linux servers:

```
Linux Server         .-,(  ),-.     can ssh                             Linux Server
 __| _            .-(          )-.------------>    .-,(  ),-.                 __| _ 
[__]|=|-----------(  Network A   )              .-(          )-.             [__]|=|
/::/|_|           '-(         ).-'              (    Network B  )------------/::/|_|
     301.2.3.4       '-.( ).-'   <------------   '-(        ).-'     321.9.8.7      
     a.example.com                  can't ssh       '-.( ).-'    b.example.net
```

So, in order to create an SSH tunnel that will allow you to connect to the remote Windows machine, this is what you need:

```
linrouter4$ ssh -L 192.168.10.4:3389:remote76.lan:3389 myuser@b.example.net
```

One that SSH connection is established, from Windows machine `workstation7` you can open an RDP connection to `linrouter4` on the default port, and what you'll get is a forwarded connection to Windows machine `remote76.lan` on the remote host.

The tunnel is configured using the `-L` flag to SSH, which takes up to 4 addresses or ports separated by colon.

The first pair indicates the address and port where to receive connections on the *local* host. The IP address needs to be an address configured on an interface on the *local* host, of course, otherwise the host wouldn't be able to receive connections at that address... We're using `linrouter4`'s address in the local network, so that other machines in the local network will be able to access that tunnel.

The next item is the local port. We're using the default port of 3389, so our RDP client can connect on the default port. If you're configuring multiple SSH tunnels or running other services on that machine using that port, you might need to pick alternative ports, in which case you'll have to reconfigure your RDP client to connect on the non-standard port. For this simple example we're bypassing that by using the default port.

The last pair of address and port are the ones that our destination host (`gateway1.lan`) is supposed to connect to when a connection reaches the tunnel on the other end. Note that name resolution will happen on the destination host, so we're able to use name `remote76.lan` even though the local `linrouter4` machine isn't able to resolve that name.

Finally, we have the remote port, which is again the default of 3389.

We then use the normal parameters to connect to the remote host, using its external address (`b.example.net`) and specifying an username (`myuser`) if necessary. Any other arguments needed for authentication or other settings can also be passed.

The `-L` flag can also take only 3 items rather than 4, in which case the local address is skipped. For example, `-L 3389:remote76.lan:3389`. But that would only expose it on localhost (127.0.0.1), which means that `linrouter4` itself can open connections through the tunnel, but not other hosts connected to that machine. (In other words, we need the full specification.)

Finally, note that we used a hostname for the remote host, but we could have used IPs too. Same for the local host, we could have used a name instead of the IP, assuming that machine will resolve the name to the internal IP.

Also would have worked:

- `-L 192.168.10.4:3389:172.24.10.76:3389`
- `-L linrouter4:3389:remote76.lan:3389`

Furthermore, you can use `'*'` at the local end to have that host accept connections on *any* interfaces: `-L '*:3389:remote76.lan:3389'`. (Note you'll want to use quotes when using `*` since the shell can interpret it as a metacharacter.) Using `*` is not ideal, since that means accesses coming from Network A (the Internet?) might be able to use the SSH tunnel to reach protected host in the remote network. Using an explicit internal-only address is definitely a more secure configuration (even though you're potentially exposing that tunnel to the *whole* internal network, unless you set up a firewall explicitly to only allow specific hosts.)

Comment: Worked like a charm, Filbranden.  Thanks very much.